# How to predict a vector using vectors in time order with machine learning techniques

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

For example, how to predict the position of a multi-point object(articulated object such as the hand with joints) based on the historical position of this object (Time Series Vector Data). Is there any machine learning technique perform well in this case and how to fulfill it in Python (eg. how to replace the original target variable with this multi-dimension vector target variable)?

something like: (Two-point object with 3 time stamps)

```
model = #such as random forest or CNN
X = [[(1.2, 1.4, 2.9), (3.5, 3.2, 1.8)], [(3.2, 3.1, 1.9), (3.1, 3.4, 1.9)], [(3.0, 3.1, 1.5), (2.8, 4.7, 2.5)]]
# 2 points * 3 Time stamps * 3 Dimension- each tuple
Y = [(2.1, 3.1, 3.5), (2.2, 3.0, 4.0)] #Just one row example
model.fit(X, Y)
#Please note that we might also consider the time order and the relationship
#between each joint (eg. Joint-joint distance should remain the same)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem *looks like* a **time series forecasting** problem. It consists of having a series of input points, from indices 1 to K and trying to predict the next points from indices K+1 to N. These points can be multi-dimensional as you describe it. For that many models exist such as **hidden Markov models** or **recurrent neural networks**.

But I also think you could better define your problem. While studying physical object position, any **prior knowledge** you can input your model will greatly improve it. For example, computing inertial, speed and acceleration metrics (from you data points) of the arm will help the model to forecast the next position. Moreover, spacial movements often are **invariant to translations and rotation***, your model should also take this in consideration.

That said, you'll need to make some research yourself to find the best way to fit you data.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. And what do you think of Kalman Filtering and LSTM for this case? As for prior, I think it can only been estimated in this case, but still not very sure how to do it. Besides the techniques, another problem is how can I apply them in python. One problem of them I am facing is that the target variable here is a vector with multi-dimension instead of a float value or label as usual. If possible, do you have any passage recommended for this case involving the methodology? Anyway, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I never heard of Kalman Filtering but it looks like it fits your problem. LSTM are recurrent networks which proved good results recently, so yes definitely a good choice. 

Having a multi-dimensional output should'nt be a problem. Many algorithms, such as LSTM can handle this. And even if the model you choose can't, then you can wrap as many as output variables you have into one predictor. Look at the MultiOutputRegressor as an example (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html).

Comment: By talking about prior, I wanted to mean that sometimes, you might improve your model by handcrafting your features. Here, computing inertial values sounds a good idea

Comment: Btw, I want to ask can I add any constraint to the multi-dimensional target? For example, if one target output (y1, y2, y3) has such a relationship that y2- y1 = y3-y2. Is it possible to add this condition for training to make the output more reasonable.